# Nested array aggregate only taking one field to match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have following json data in mongodb.

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "user1",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "user2",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "user3",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "user4",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "user5",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "name": "user6",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "name": "user7",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "name": "user8",
    "userActivities": [
      {
        "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
        "progress": "Success."
      },
      {
        "actionTaken": "logout",
        "progress": "Success."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am querying data for pagination as following.

```json
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "userActivities": {
                "actionTaken": "Sign in."
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "name": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "userActivities": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$userActivities",
                    "as": "userActivities",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$$userActivities.actionTaken",
                            "Sign in."
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$skip": 2
    },
    {
        "$limit": 2
    }
]
```

But not getting any data even though it matches filter criteria. If I remove `progress` field from sample data then it gives me data.

Is it something should be done differently when multiple fields are there in column to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation in your `$match` stage.

```
{
  "$match": {
    "userActivities.actionTaken": "Sign in."
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eDQKSjW44Tu)

Comment: tried. didn't work.

Comment: This [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition) may be useful for you.

Comment: May be I was doing something wrong last time. But it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the "progress" in your match stage otherways you match only objects with the single field actionTaken that do not exist in the collection :

```
 {
  "$match": {
    "userActivities": {
      "actionTaken": "Sign in.",
      "progress": "Success."
    }
  }
 }
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MkRmjKf5XzU)

Comment: this is not feasible. to add progress also in filter as it is not actual filter.

Comment: indeed you better search via dot notation "userActivities.actionTaken"  as proposed by @Yong Shun and create index on that field ...

Comment: I got the answer. Have posted now.

Comment: search by dot notation with index will be faster ...

Comment: elemMatch better be used when you have more then one field together to be searched  in the sub object ...

Comment: but dot notation is not working. I tried that.

Comment: ok. create index on that field. I missed that part. elemMatch is fine at the moment as I am not having that big data in the table. May be I will consider for other tables probably. But other tables are not having nested data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243520/discussion-between-r2d2-and-anonymous-creator).

Answer (score 0):

Got answer by taking help from one person. I had to use $elemMatch as following.

```json
    [
      {
        "$match": {
          "userActivities": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "actionTaken": "Sign in."
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "name": -1
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "name": 1,
          "userActivities": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$userActivities",
              "as": "userActivities",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": ["$$userActivities.actionTaken", "Sign in."]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$skip": 2
      },
      {
        "$limit": 2
      }
    ]
```